# Delete multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails model where I would like to destroy multiple records from one call from the controller. My controller method is something like

```
def destroy_multiple
   Model.destroy_all(params[:id_list])
end
```

My question is what is the best way to submit the ids? As a POST request? GET request? URL parameter on a DELETE request? what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with either POST or DELETE request, but I would prefer to do it as a DELETE. You can do something like this:

```
Model.where(id: params[:id_list]).destroy_all
```

Comment: How should I pass the params with a delete request? as url parameters?

Comment: Yes send it as url parameters like "delete_path(ids_list: [1,2,3])"

Answer (score 2):

Pass the params in the url, something like /model/destroy_multiple?ids=[1,2,3]

Then in the controller:

```
def destroy_multiple
   Model.destroy_all(params[:id_list])
end
```

**But remember:**

- `destroy` / `destroy_all`: The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their destroy method
- `delete` / `delete_all`: All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their :destroy method

If your model doesn't have associated records you should use **delete_all because is faster.**